# Разобрать JSON и получить SQL

Tags: php, sql, json

Имеется JSON который передается браузером на сервер. Этот JSON нужно разобрать так, чтобы получить SQL запрос.
Дело в том, что структура у данных всегда одна, а вот вложенность может быть больше или меньше!

Сам JSON:

```js
[{
   "5":
         [{
            "248":
                  [{
                     "777" : ""
                  }]
         },
         {
            "249":
                  [{
                     "251" : ""
                  },
                  {
                     "250" : ""
                  },
                  {
                     "252":
                           [{
                              "400" : ""
                           }]
                  }]
         }]
}]
```

Там где цифры - это значения, а название полей опишу ниже.
Я помещаю этот JSON в `json_decode` и получаю массив, с которым далее нужно работать.

После обработки массива, на выходе нужно получить следующий SQL:

```sql
district = 5
AND
(
    (village = 248 AND street = 777)
    OR
    (
        village = 249
        AND
        (
            street = 251
            OR
            street = 250
            OR
            (street = 252 AND house = 400)
        )
    )
)
```

Там где district это первый уровень вложенности, village - второй, street - третий и т.д.
Я пытался сделать так:
Создал массив:

```php
$tables = array("district", "village", "street", "house");
```

и в зависимости от уровня вложенности подставлял значение.

Структура у JSON всегда одна, а уровней вложенности, как я уже говорил, может быть больше или меньше.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что у вас проблемы в структуре базы. Приведите пример вашей структуры и опишите задачу.

Comment: Вы думаете со структурой таблицы что-то не так?! Она имеет составной индекс CREATE INDEX _district ON users(district, village, street, house); и если обратить внимание на составной индекс, я дума, запрос корректный или что-то там не так? UPD: Ответ можно писать только в одну строчку? Ппц неудобно

Comment: У вас в json цифры - это название полей, а не значения. В этом может быть дело?

Answer (score 3):

А в чём, собственно, проблема? Проходимся банальной рекурсией:

```
$json = '[{"5":[{"248":[{"777":""}]},{"249":[{"251":""},{"250":""},{"252":[{"400":""}]}]}]}]';
echo sql(json_decode($json, true), ['district', 'village', 'street', 'house'], 0);

function sql ($query, $fields, $level)
{
    $exprs = [];
    foreach ($query as $values) {
        foreach ($values as $value => $subquery) {
            $expr = '(' . $fields[$level] . '=' . $value . ')';
            if (is_array($subquery))
                $expr = '(' . $expr . ' AND (' . sql($subquery, $fields, $level + 1) . '))';
            $exprs[] = $expr;
        }
    }
    return implode(' OR ', $exprs);
}
```

Имеем:

```sql
((district=5) AND (((village=248) AND ((street=777))) OR ((village=249) AND ((street=251) OR (street=250) OR ((street=252) AND ((house=400)))))))
```

Экранирование значений и оптимизацию скобочек оставляю как домашнее задание.

Comment: Знаете кто Вы? Вы, мать его, гений) Спасибо огромное !!!

Comment: Я почему-то старался пройти рекурсию так. чтобы лишних скобок не было, не знаю, зачем мне это в голову ударило. Пусть SQL сам со скобками разбирается)